# How to find String using Python Script and compare with another txt file

Tags: python

Looking for a solution using python script as below:

I m having two text files having a thousand lines in each file.

Let's say File1.txt and file2.txt, each file have a key and its value
i.e.
SaveButton.save=Save (here SaveButton.save is key and value is Save) in file1.txtx and SaveButton.save=xyz in file2.txt

Now using Python Script I want to check if SaveButton.save key(from file1.txt) exist in File2.txt if exist then it should save in csv or xlx as below:
file1    file2
SaveButton.save  Save      xyz

Scenario 2:

in file1.txt/file2.txt it should not have a duplicate key or empty (which does not have value)

Looking for expert advice for the above thanks in advance

Comment: So, the format is exactly A=B in both files?

Comment: 1) Go through the file line-by-line. Split on `=`, save to dict or something. Go through a second file in the same manner. Also check existence in the first dict -> if it exists, add to result. After going through all, save the result. 2) You check whether key is already in the dict and whether value is empty when going line-by-line. You can later use the dict to correct the file.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You can use pandas to read both files to dataframe and take the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

**Sidefact:** Maybe take a look at `.ini` files. Their only purpose is storing keys and their values. In addition to this you can split key/value pairs into logical sections. Take
a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) for more informations.

As already mentioned in the comments from some others, I would go through the lines and split on a specific delimeter, which would be `=` in your case.

```
def gather_file_informations(file: str): # e.g.: gather_file_informations("test.txt")
    dictonary = {} # contains all key/value pairs
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            key, value = line.split('=')
            dictionary[key] = value
    return dictonary
```

Consider that you maybe have to check if there are blank lines or lines you want to ignore before inserting them into your file dictonary.

You should have two dictonaries after scanning both files. Throughout this you can easily check if any key is given or not and also edit them later on.

```
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        print("Key exists in other file")
    else:
        print("Key doesn't exist in other file")
```

Hopefully this helps you solving your problem, sheers!

Comment: @Matiiss also see [**`ConfigParser`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)